# Getting postfix to log to a file on docker

Tags: postfix, docker, smtp, logging, sasl

I have created a docker image based on Ubuntu 20.04 with postfix and dovecot. I also installed syslog-ng in hope to solve my problem, but it didn't work.

Thing is, I want to use fail2ban to prevent force brute attacks, and I need postfix/smtp/sasl logs. I configured postfix to log to a file adding `maillog_file = /var/log/postfix.log` to `main.cf`. It does creates a postfix.log file, but no information is logged om smtp/sasl authentication.

These messages are not shown on `messages`, `syslog` or `mail.log` files, which have almost no data.

Any tips on how to achieve complete authentication logging for postfix so that fail2ban can catch it?

Comment: have you checked log file permissions?

Comment: Not really, but since the postfix.log was created and start up and shutdown events are logged, I am not sure it is related to permissions.